# Is there a notation for saying that a function is defined on some subset of a set?

Tags: functions, notation, terminology

Let $X,Y$ be sets and let $f$ assign to every $x \in X$ some unique $y \in Y$. Then we may write $f: X \to Y$. This notation has the advantage that $f(X)$ need not be $Y$ but must be "within" $Y$. But it has a "disadvantage" that $f$ must eat every point of $X$.
So I wonder if there is in literature any notation that may "remedy" this relatively unpleasant feature.

If there is one such, then we may be kept from constantly saying, say "let $A$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and let $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$...".

Comment: Without any restriction on what the subset of the given set is, this is the notion of *partial function*.

Comment: Sometimes one uses $X \supset D \xrightarrow{f} Y$.

Comment: Often written as $f : D \subset X \to Y$

Comment: Thank you for bringing those in. I should have specified things more clearly in my question. Personally I tend to avoid squeezing too much information together, say I avoid writing $x \in A \subset \mathbb{R}$, and hence I implicitly ruled out the choice. But thank you anyway. @HagenvonEitzen, Daniel Fischer, Simon

Comment: I am not a native English speaker, so if you have some idea as to rephrase my question, please kindly do so. :)

Comment: For a partial function from $X$ to $Y$ one might write $f: X ⊇\to Y$.